# Rotation of a vector around a rotation axis

Tags: physics, rotation

Is there an easy way (like a defined function) in Mathematica to rotate a direction vector around a rotation axis for θ degrees?

For instance: rotate `[3,4,5]` around `[1,1,1]` for `30` degrees.

Comment: Did you already look at the docs for `RotationTransform[]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can play with Viewpoint and ViewAngle to get better view of this. The black arrow is the vector `{3,4,5}` and the red one is `{1,1,1}` stretched a little to make it easier to see. This is done using

[image]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Manipulate[
 r = RotationMatrix[theta Degree, 5 {1, 1, 1}];
 Graphics3D[
  {
   {Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, r . {3, 4, 5}}]},
   {Red, Line[{{0, 0, 0}, 5 {1, 1, 1}}]}
   }, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, BaseStyle -> 14, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 6}, {0, 6}, {0, 6}}],
 {{theta, 45, "theta"}, 0, 360, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {theta}
 ]
```

[image]